# Is there a way to mock the firebase_admin credentials.Certificate class in Django?

Tags: python, django, firebase-authentication, mocking, django-unittest

In my project, FirebaseAuthentication is used and while running the test cases(pipenv run python manage.py test) I am getting the following error - **ValueError: Invalid certificate argument: "None". Certificate argument must be a file path, or a dict containing the parsed file contents.**

authentication.py

```
from firebase_admin import auth
from firebase_admin import credentials
cred = credentials.Certificate(os.getenv('FIREBASE_ADMIN_KEY_PATH'))
default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred)
```

tests.py(where I have not imported authentication file)

```
from django.test import TestCase
class A(TestCase):
    ....
```

I am trying to run specific app test case but somehow it is trying to import authentication.py. That is why `cred = credentials.Certificate(os.getenv('FIREBASE_ADMIN_KEY_PATH'))` is getting executed. I have identified that cred and default_app are declared at global level. And I cannot move it to other function or classes for the same file. I have noticed that `cred = credentials.Certificate(os.getenv('FIREBASE_ADMIN_KEY_PATH'))` returns the object and not specific data and also calls the Firebase API for authentication. How can I mock this two line at a global level?